# Display a White Box Below Safe Area

Tags: ios, iphone-x

How can I display a white box below the bottom edge of the safe area of the iPhone X (such that the home indicator sits on said white box)? I'd prefer to do this programmatically so I'm not messing with the storyboard.

Comment: you want safe area background color is white am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (in viewDidLoad):

```
UIView *testView = [UIView new];
testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[testView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
[testView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
[testView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
[testView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
```

**EDIT**

If you only want this done for iOS 11+ (which makes sense) but support previous versions then do something like this (assuming Xcode 9+):

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIView *testView = [UIView new];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:testView];
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [testView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [testView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [testView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
    [testView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

Comment: Works! Last question: I get 'safeAreaLayoutGuide' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer as a warning. Will that cause any problems for devices on iOS 9/10 or will they just ignore the code (which is fine since iPhone X is 11+)

Comment: Indeed safeAreaLayoutGuide is only available on iOS 11.  If you want your app to work for iOS 9 & 10 then you are going to have to detect the iOS version and do something different.  In fact as this is for the iPhone X only you can just skip this entirely if it's not iOS 11.  I will edit the answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! and the * after 11.0, I presume means all versions after 11.0 included?

Comment: Yep technically it's @available(x,y,z) where it's the iOS version x.y.z and a '*' indicates any.  So @available(11,*) is 11.anything and @available(11,2,*) would be 11.2.anything.